Definition of tensor product seems to contradict universal property
$\def\vc#1{\vec{\mathbf{#1}}}$
$\def\cv#1{\tilde{\mathbf{#1}}}$
$\def\qty#1{\left(#1\right)}$
$\def\F{\mathbb{F}}$
In a number of standard textbooks on tensors for physics students (e.g. Tensors: The Mathematics of Relativity Theory and Continuum Mechanics) we find definitions of the tensor product like
$$
[ \cv{u}\otimes \cv{v}]\qty{\vc{a},\vc{b}}:=\cv{u}(\vc{a})\cv{v}(\vc{b}) \tag{I}
$$
where $\cv{u},\cv{v}$ are covectors and $\vc{a},\vc{b}$ are vectors. Reading this expression,  $\cv{u}\otimes \cv{v}$ seems to be a bilinear form $V \times V \rightarrow \F$ ($V$ is the vector space over a field $\F$).
However the universal property of the tensor product only allows for any bilinear map
$B: V^* \times V^* \rightarrow \F$ to be factored through a unique linear map $\beta: V^* \otimes V^* \rightarrow \F$ so that
$$
\beta(\cv{u} \otimes \cv{v}) = B(\cv{u},\cv{v})
$$
Therefore bilinear forms can only be linked to a tensor product through a linear map.
Based on this can we say that the tensor product of two covectors is a bilinear form?

I don't understand what you're asking. First of all, why is there a problem of consistency here? Also, where do you get that universal property from? The usual universal property of the tensor product concerns itself with bilinear maps $V \times V \to \mathbb{F}$, not with ones from the dual spaces. In any case, I recommend taking a look at Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" Chapter 12 for a well-written and mathematically rigorous treatment of the same construction of the tensor product.

The universal property of the tensor product applies to any bilinear map $U \times V \rightarrow W$ were $U,V,W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces (see Proposition 12.7 in the book you recommended).

"the universal property [...] only allows for [...]" - I think you're looking at it a bit backwards; the universal property is a way to say what's true while abstracting away the details of the construction. But if you have a specific construction and are not concerned with being overly general, you can make use of those details. The book constructs 2nd order tensors as members of a vectors space of bilinear forms from the get-go, and then the tensor product definition implicitly selects a member $\tilde u\otimes \tilde v$ of that space that corresponds to the product of $\tilde u, \tilde v$

@FilipMilovanović thanks for your comment. I am trying to see whether this construction makes sense; I guess since the definition used has all the properties of the tensor product we can use it.

@FilipMilovanović I just realised the problem with the specific construction (if necessary I can post it as a new question). We define $\tilde{\bf u}\otimes\tilde{\bf v}({\bf x},{\bf y}):= \tilde{\bf u}({\bf x})\tilde{\bf v}({\bf y})$ so that $V^* \otimes V^$ is the vector space of bilinear forms. But then how do we define the dual to $V^ \otimes V^$? With this specific construction it is not clear what is $\phi: V^ \otimes V^* \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$.

Tensor products
A canonical definition of a tensor product is by the universal property:
The tensor product of the vector spaces $U$, $V$ is a vector space $U \otimes V$, together with a bilinear function $\otimes : U \times V \to U \otimes V$, satisfying the property

For any vector space $W$ and bilinear function $F : U \times V \to W$, there is a unique linear function $f : U \otimes V \to W$ such that the following diagram commutes
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD} U \times V @>\otimes>> U \otimes V \\ 
@. \rlap{\hspace{1em} \underset{F}{}} \style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(25deg)}{\xrightarrow[\rule{2em}{0em}]{}} @VVfV\\
@. W \end{CD}

The definition is correct because we can prove that given $U$ and $V$, there is a unique space up to isomorphism satisfying the universal property.
Relation to bilinear forms
In the case of tensor products of the form $V^* \otimes V^*$, its elements can be canonically interpreted as bilinear forms $V \times V \to \mathbb{F}$. Formally there is a canonical vector space monomorphism $j : V^* \otimes V^* \to \operatorname{Bil}(V \times V, \mathbb{F})$, satisfying
$$j(u \otimes v)(a, b) = u(a) \cdot v(b).$$
If $V$ is finitely dimensional, $j$ is surjective and so an isomorphism. Then we can freely identify every tensor with its corresponding bilinear forms, so that simple tensors $u \otimes v$ are mapped to the forms $B(a, b) = u(a) \cdot v(b)$, and arbitrary tensors (finite sums of simple tensors) are mapped adequately by additivity. With $V$ infinitely dimensional the identification is still possible, except not all bilinear forms will be expressible as a tensor.
Conclusion
The definition of a tensor product via the universal property is powerful and convenient, but takes some understanding to master. On the other hand, bilinear forms are quite easy to grasp and in specific cases they are equivalent to tensors. My guess is that physicists want to avoid the complications of the general tensor product and so define tensors directly as bilinear forms, which is sufficiently true for their purposes.

Thanks for your detailed answer. You mention that "...there is a canonical vector space monomorphism $j:V^* \otimes V^* \rightarrow {\rm Hom}(V \times V,\mathbb{F}
)$ satisfying $j(u \otimes v)(a,b)=u(a) v(b)$." So since $j$ is a bijective map, we can map each tensor product $u \otimes v$ to a unique bilinear form. Therefore instead of every time using  $j(u \otimes v)(a,b)=u(a) v(b)$ we can simplify matters in a physics book by writing $(u \otimes v)(a,b)=u(a)b(v)$. Is my understanding correct?

Yes, we identify $u \otimes v$ with $j(u \otimes v)$.

I don't think the notation $\mathrm{Hom}(V\times V, \mathbb{F})$ is correct here. It should be $\mathrm{Bil}(V\times V, \mathbb{F})$ (for bilinear maps) or $\mathrm{Hom}(V\otimes V, \mathbb{F})$.

@AlexKruckman I actually tried to google how bilinear forms are usually denoted, but I couldn't find it. Thanks!
